# App crash when UITableView Scrolls up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I wonder why my app crashes when i scroll my UITableView up.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSArray *arrayForNames=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[objContentManager getDuasNamesByGroupName:[arrayDuaGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]]; 


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
// implementation on cell    
}
```

When i scroll up program crashes at `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

I saw the tutorials and all i can't find any different implementation there, it scrolls down pretty smooth but when i scroll back up it crashes straight away, I not figuring out where m doing wrong

```
> 2011-06-24 15:07:10.976
> Tasbeeh[503:207] *** Terminating app
> due to uncaught exception
> 'NSRangeException', reason: '***
> -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
> *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation                     
> 0x02553919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib                  
> 0x023685de objc_exception_throw + 47
>   2   CoreFoundation                   
> 0x0254958c -[__NSArrayI
> objectAtIndex:] + 236     3   Tasbeeh    
> 0x00002922 -[ClassDuaTableCategory
> tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] +
> 553   4   UIKit                        
> 0x00326a3f
> -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:]
> + 619     5   UIKit                               0x0031cad2
> -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75     6   UIKit                            
> 0x00331337
> -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1348    7   UIKit                              
> 0x003294bc -[UITableView
> layoutSubviews] + 242     8   QuartzCore 
> 0x040e30d5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
> + 177     9   QuartzCore                          0x040e2e05 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
>   10  QuartzCore                       
> 0x040e264c
> _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE
> + 302     11  QuartzCore                          0x040e22b0
> _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292    12  QuartzCore                         
> 0x040e9f5b
> _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv
> + 99  13  CoreFoundation                      0x02534d1b
> __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
> + 27  14  CoreFoundation                      0x024c9987 __CFRunLoopDoObservers +
> 295   15  CoreFoundation               
> 0x02492c17 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575  16 
> CoreFoundation                     
> 0x02492280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>   17  CoreFoundation                   
> 0x024921a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    18
> GraphicsServices                   
> 0x02cb82c8 GSEventRunModal + 217  19 
> GraphicsServices                   
> 0x02cb838d GSEventRun + 115   20  UIKit
> 0x002c4b58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>   21  Tasbeeh                          
> 0x00002024 main + 102     22  Tasbeeh    
> 0x00001fb5 start + 53 ) terminate
> called after throwing an instance of
> 'NSException' Program received signal:
> “SIGABRT”.
```

Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: crash log plz and implementation cell also provide here..

Comment: i ve pasted it already please have a look

Comment: You might want to add `getDuasNamesByGroupName` method, and code showing how you are filling & altering `arrayDuaGroups`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that indexPath goes to a value that points to an invalid index of the array `arrayDuaGroups`
?

Comment: thats the point but why it crashes at  `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` why is that so

Comment: watching the exception stack, it seems the error is on 
0x0254958c -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 236 3
and not in the 
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Answer (score 3):

Please check the nib file of your tableview controller.

There should be a "table view" under your view controller.

Click to see the attribute inspector of the table view.

Check the "content" to see if it is assigned  "Dynamic Prototypes" or "static cell"?

Change from "static cell" to "Dynamic Prototypes" might be able to solve your problem.

Comment: This hasn't helped me with my tableview having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting the cell = nil if and let only the cell = part , if it's what i think it is it will fix it

```
 // if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
//    }
```

EDIT: 
AFTER viewing the log -
The problem is with the array as data source, when it tries to rebuild the cell  it does not find anything in your array(arrayDuaGroups), it is empty , declare your array in the class interface with the retain property and check to se if the arrayDuaGroups is empty

Comment: Thanks Radu i guess i ve a logical problem that is producing this bug

Answer (score 0):

Try with using below

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

EDITED:
```

You have issue with `NSArray` , You are trying to access an element from the array which doesn't exist,

Your `arrayDuaGroups` array  does'nt have any object at index `indexPath.section`.

Check the `arrayDuaGroups` array content and length before fetching the object.

[arrayDuaGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]

Answer (score 0):

It seems array out of bounds exception. Your array is the problem. you should not allocate array into cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Fill the data in viewDidLoad method and then use that array to display data in cell.

Comment: thanks for help yet i think i ve logical problem when m managing rows in a group

Comment: As per you your crash log your problem is due to an aray out of bounds exception definitely indexPath is going to a value that points to an invalid index of the array.